# default option is not part of parameters hash sent to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following select field:

```
  <%= f.select :lead_status_id, LeadStatus.all.collect {|status| [ status.name, status.id ] }, { selected: LeadStatus.where(name: "Initial").first.id }, {class: "form-control", disabled: "disabled"} %>
```

The name attribute of the select looks like this: lead[lead_status_id]. And the option like this:

```
<option selected="selected" value="2">Initial</option>
```

So I have a default option selected, and I want that default option to be sent to server. Its only purpose is to let user know what status they are. Thus, I set the field disable so user can't edit it. The problem is its never sent as part of the parameters hash sent to server and thus my validates_presence_of :lead_status_id is failing.

Why isn't it sent in params hash to server and how can I address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why isn't it sent in params hash to server and how can I address this?

*If you look at your select, you have disabled it and **disabled fields are not sent as parameters by form.***

**Fix**

*If it would have been input field you could have simply set it to readonly **but there isn't an option to set a [select as readonly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)*** so you need to change your UI. You have following options:

a. ***Don't show your select at all and add a hidden field in your form so that your lead_status_id is send to controller***

b. ***You can make a div and then make it look like a select by css. Include a hidden field in your form again and then set its value to whatever is your default value***